# Finding the largest odd number of 3 variables - feedback

Tags: python, python-3.x

below is the code I've written to try and solve this problem. However whenever I have the case: z>y (where both z and y are odd and x is even), as below, I get the output as "y is the largest odd".

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
x= 2
y= 3
z= 17

#condition 1: all odds

if x%2 !=0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2!=0:
            if (x>y) and (x>z):
                print('x is largest odd')
            elif (y>x) and (y>z):
                    print ('y is largest odd')
            elif (z>x) and (z>y):
                print('z is largest odd')

# condition 2: z is even but x & y are odd
            else:
                if x%2!=0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2==0:
                        if (x>y):
                            print('x is largest odd')
                        else:
                            print('y is largest odd')
                        
#condition 3: y is even but x and z are odd
                else:
                    if x%2 !=0 and y%2==0 and z%2 !=0:
                            if (x>z):
                                print('x is largest odd')
                            else:
                                print('z is largest odd')
                    
#condition 4 x is even by y and z are odd
                    else:
                        if x%2==0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2 !=0:
                            if (z>y):
                                print('z is largest odd')
                            else:
                                print('y is largest odd')
else:
    if x%2 !=0:
        print('x is largest odd')
    elif y%2 !=0:
        print('y is largest odd')
    elif z%2 !=0:
        print ('z is largest odd')
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2==0 and z%2==0 :
        print ('no odds')
```

Comment: What did you find when you tried to debug this code?

Comment: One way is to put only your odd numbers into a list and then just do `max(odds)`.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to show a bit of my process of debugging for you, as it may help.

I added a number (1 through 4) to each of the 'print y is the largest odd' to figure out which one is being printed.

In the example you gave, you're reaching this part of the code.

```
else:
    if x%2 !=0:
        print('x is largest odd')
    elif y%2 !=0:
        print('y is largest odd')
    elif z%2 !=0:
        print ('z is largest odd')
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2==0 and z%2==0 :
        print ('no odds')
```

As :

```
elif y%2 !=0:
```

comes before the next else if, you're printing "y is the largest odd" before reaching

```
elif z%2 !=0:
```

Now why would we be reaching this part of the code and not catching at :

```
#condition 4 x is even by y and z are odd
                    else:
                        if x%2==0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2 !=0:
                            if (z>y):
                                print('z is largest odd')
                            else:
                                print('y is largest odd')
```

The answer is in your "if, else" loops. You're using if, indenting to another level, making a new if, then your else is going to that new if, three times.

What you would want to do instead is something along these lines :

```
if x%2 !=0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2!=0:

elif x%2!=0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2==0:

elif x%2 !=0 and y%2==0 and z%2 !=0:

elif x%2==0 and y%2 !=0 and z%2 !=0:

else:
```

and ditch the multiple (inappropriate) uses of else.

Answer (score 2):

If you store all your numbers in a list you could use `max()` and list comprehension to determine the highest odd rather easily.

You could also build in some checks that if your comprehension returned `[]` then output that no odds were found.

```
numbers = [2, 3, 17]
odds = [x for x in numbers if x%2 != 0]

if odds:
    print(max(odds))
else:
    print('No odds Found')
```